# how to obtain interval from date on postgres in days

Tags: postgresql, date, intervals

I have two columns, say "2010-10-26" and "2010-08-23" and I would like to obtain the interval in days, what is the best way to do this on a select query taking into account that there are months with 30,31,29,28 days? Is there any function that already does this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the manual before asking. This is all explained there: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are already in the date format, it's very easy:

```
SELECT '10/26/2010'::date - '08/23/2010'::date;
```

OR:

```
SELECT date '2001-10-01' - date '2001-09-28'; // outputs integer 3
```